# Кодировочка mariadb

Tags: utf-8, mariadb

Есть "замечательный" символ "".
И при попытке Insert его в таблицу получается, вот это:

```
ERROR 1300 (HY000): Invalid utf8mb4 character string: '\xF0\x9F\x90\x89'
```

Какая кодировка нужна?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подозреваю, что это ошибка на "стороне клиента".

Попробуйте:

```
   SET NAMES utf8mb4;
```

---

MariaDB под рукой нет, вот как ведёт себя mysql:

```
mysql> describe Storage;
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| p     | varchar(255) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| val   | longtext     | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO Storage VALUES('Dragon', '');
ERROR 1366 (HY000): Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x90\x89' for column 'val' at row 1
mysql> SET Names utf8mb4;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0,00 sec)

mysql> INSERT INTO Storage VALUES('Dragon', '');
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,10 sec)

mysql> UPDATE Storage SET p = '';
Query OK, 1 row affected (0,20 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM Storage;
+------+------+
| p    | val  |
+------+------+
|      |      |
+------+------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

Comment: Пробовал. (NAMES)
Данный символ я пробовал "запихивать" с помощью. JDBC ну и ручками.

Comment: Хочу отметить что символы: ☢ ☣ ☣ ☢ ♿ ☹   спокойно лежат в БД.

Comment: Такс оно заработало :) Видимо руки кривые )

Comment: Спасибо за столь подробный ответ

Comment: Лень проверять, но скорее всего остальные символы влазят в `utf8` (3 байта)